# Super-weird issue triggering "Segmentation Fault"

Tags: c, d, dmd

I won't go very deep into the issue (the codebase is already thousands of lines and quite complex), so I'll try to miniminise the... "window" to what I've spotted.

**Here's the routine triggering the "Segmentation Fault" :**

```
extern (C) 
{
    void* Statements_new() { return cast(void*)(new Statements()); }
    void  Statements_add(Statements s, Statement st) 
    { 
        //writeln("In here"); 
        if (s is null) writeln("StatemenTS are null"); 
        else writeln("not null : "~ typeid(s).name); 

        if (st is null) writeln("statement is null"); 
        else writeln("not null : " ~ typeid(st).name); 

        s.add(st); 

        //writeln("Out of here"); 

    }

}
```

**A few notes :**

- The declared methods are nothing but "bindings" so that native routines can be called directly from C code (Bison actually).
- The `Statements_add` function is called with a `Statements` object and a subclassed `Statement` object.

**Now, the weirdness of it :**

- The error doesn't happen all the time (actually it doesn't happen like 99% of the time), but when it does, the `s.add(st);` statement seems the culprit.
- Never ever is one of the 2 parameters (`s`,`st`) `null`.
- Now, if I comment the 2 `if... writeln... typeid` statements, the error is there.
- If I uncomment them (they don't do anything, huh?), it always works - fixed - bingo!

What's going on???

---

A few more details :

- **Compiler :** DMD64 D Compiler v2.065
- **Debugger :** lldb
- **OS       :** OSX 10.9.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are passing the only reference of an object allocated in D code from the D heap to non-D code, then you *must* either [register it as a GC root](http://dlang.org/phobos/core_memory.html#.GC.addRoot), or change your code to use `malloc` instead of allocating from the managed D heap. Otherwise, the GC will think that the object is unused, and collect it to free memory.

Comment: Omg... I seem to have totally forgotten about the Garbage Collection... Awesome answer! It would have taken me around 100 more debugging sessions to figure out! ;-)

Comment: Oh man, I had something like this happen to me too but it wasn't reliable so I didn't even notice it was happening until like a month later when the program had more event traffic and the bug actually started triggering every few seconds instead of going several runs without it. In my case, I was writing pointers back to the application with the self pipe trick... I didn't think they were leaving the app, but while sitting in the kernel pipe buffer, they GC couldn't see them and freed the object! Pain to track down. I think I wrote about it twice in my book too, once you see it tho you know it