# Another weird issue with Garbage Collection?

Tags: garbage-collection, segmentation-fault, d, dmd

**OK, so here's the culprit method :**

```
class FunctionDecl
{
    // More code...

    override void execute()
    {
        //...
        writeln("Before setting... " ~ name);
        Glob.functions.set(name,this);
        writeln("After setting." ~ name);
        //...
    }
}
```

**And here's what happens :**

- If omit the `writeln("After setting." ~ name);` line, the program crashes, just at this point
- If I keep it in (using the `name` attribute is the key, not the `writeln` itself), it works just fine.

So, I suppose `this` is automatically garbage collected? Why is that? (A pointer to some readable reference related to GC and D would be awesome)

How can I solve that?

---

**UPDATE :**

Just tried a `GC.disable()` at the very beginning of my code. And... automagically, everything works again! So, that was the culprit as I had suspected. The thing is : how is this solvable with*out* totally eliminating Garbage Collection?

---

**UPDATE II :**

Here's **the full code of `functionDecl.d`** - "unnecessary" code omitted :

```
//================================================
// Imports
//================================================

// ...

//================================================
// C Interface for Bison
//================================================

extern (C) 
{
    void* FunctionDecl_new(char* n, Expressions i, Statements s) { return cast(void*)(new FunctionDecl(to!string(n),i,s)); }
    void* FunctionDecl_newFromReference(char* n, Expressions i, Expression r) { return cast(void*)(new FunctionDecl(to!string(n),i,r)); }
}

//================================================
// Functions
//================================================

class FunctionDecl : Statement
{
    // .. class variables ..

    this(string n, Expressions i, Statements s)
    {
        this(n, new Identifiers(i), s);
    }

    this(string n, Expressions i, Expression r)
    {
        this(n, new Identifiers(i), r);
    }

    this(string n, Identifiers i, Statements s)
    {
        // .. implementation ..
    }

    this(string n, Identifiers i, Expression r)
    {
        // .. implementation ..
    }

        // .. other unrelated methods ..

    override void execute()
    {
        if (Glob.currentModule !is null) parentModule = Glob.currentModule.name;

        Glob.functions.set(name,this);
    }
}
```

**Now as for what `Glob.functions.set(name,this);` does :**

- `Glob` is an instance holding global definitions
- `function` is the class instance dealing with defined functions (it comes with a `FunctionDecl[] list`
- `set` simply does that : `list ~= func;`

---

**P.S.** I'm 99% sure it has something to do with this one : [Super-weird issue triggering "Segmentation Fault"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23247986/super-weird-issue-triggering-segmentation-fault), though I'm still not sure what went wrong this time...

Comment: @DejanLekic `Glob.functions` contains a `FunctionDecl[] list;`. So all this `set` does is `void set(string name, FunctionDecl f) { list ~= f; }`.

Comment: @DejanLekic Also please note that the specific point of code causes a crash like after 100 it has already been successfully executed. And then it breaks. That's why I'm suspecting GC.

Comment: are you dynamically linking the 2 together?

Comment: @ratchetfreak I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. All I'm doing is what I say in my comment to DejanLekic...

Comment: are you compiling 1 into a dll and compiling the other into the exe? If it is all in one exe then you are linking statically

Comment: @ratchetfreak I still have no clue what you're talking about. First off, there are neither "dll"s, nor "exe"s; I'm an OSX user. Secondly, are you talking about the files containing the 2 modules? I still don't get it...

Comment: dll == compile with -shared.  But can you post more code?

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe As you may (or may not) have guessed by my recent D-related postings, I'm building a compiler(actually, an interpreter) 100% in D. (No, I'm obviously not a D guru, it's the first time I decided to try it out on a serious project). So, the codebase is rather complex, that's why I try to post as specific code as possible (that's what `lldb` pointed to, and that's what I managed to isolate). If it makes any difference, `FunctionDecl` instances are first created through C/Bison code. Let me see what I can post...

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe I've posted more code. Hope that helps. (This thing is driving me crazy, so I'd be more than grateful for some input! :-))

Comment: In the time between the object being new'd and the execute method being called, are you doing any other allocations? If you pass it to C, the GC might wipe it out early.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe Actually the object is being created from Bison (C), using my D bindings. So, I suppose you're right. But, how could I avoid that?

Comment: In that function_new, immediately add it to a global AA OR create it with malloc (and of course, free it with free). I'll write it up as an answer so there's more room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the C function is allocating the object, but D doesn't keep a reference. If `FunctionDecl_new` is called back-to-back in a tight memory environment, here's what would happen:

1. the first one calls, creating a new object. That pointer goes into the land of C, where the D GC can't see it.
2. The second one goes, allocating another new object. Since memory is tight (as far as the GC pool is concerned), it tries to run a collection cycle. It finds the object from (1), but cannot find any live pointers to it, so it frees it.
3. The C function uses that freed object, causing the segfault.

The segfault won't always run because if there's memory to spare, the GC won't free the object when you allocate the second one, it will just use its free memory instead of collecting. That's why omitting the `writeln` can get rid of the crash: the `~` operator allocates, which might just put you over the edge of that memory line, triggering a collection (and, of course, running the `~` gives the gc a chance to run in the first place. If you never GC allocate, you never GC collect either - the function looks kinda like `gc_allocate() { if(memory_low) gc_collect(); return GC_malloc(...); }`)

There's three solutions:

- Immediately store a reference in the `FunctionDecl_new` function in a D structure, before returning:

  ```
  FunctionDecl[] fdReferences;

  void* FunctionDecl_new(...) {
       auto n = new FunctionDecl(...);
       fdReferences ~= n; // keep the reference for later so the GC can see it
       return cast(void*) n;
  }
  ```
- Call `GC.addRoot` on the pointer right before you return it to C. (I don't like this solution, I think the array is better, a lot simpler.)
- Use `malloc` to create the object to give to C:

  ```
  void* FunctionDecl_new(...) {
      import std.conv : emplace;
      import core.stdc.stdlib : malloc;
      enum size = __traits(classInstanceSize, FunctionDecl);

      auto memory = malloc(size)[0 .. size]; // need to slice so we know the size

      auto ref = emplace!FunctionDecl(memory, /* args to ctor */); // create the object in the malloc'd block

      return memory.ptr; // give the pointer to C
  }
  ```

Then, of course, you ought to `free` the pointer when you know it is no longer going to be used, though if you don't, it isn't really wrong.

---

The general rule I follow btw is any memory that crosses language barriers for storage (usage is different) ought to be allocated similarly to what that language expects: So if you pass data to C or C++, allocate it in a C fashion, e.g. with `malloc`. This will lead to the least surprising friction as it gets stored.

If the object is just being temporarily used, it is fine to pass a plain pointer to it, since a temp usage isn't stored or freed by the receiving function so there's less danger there. Your reference will still exist too, if nothing else, on the call stack.